# Como creo una autenticacion basica en rest api codeigniter4

Tags: php7, codeigniter-4

Hola amigos estoy tratando de crear una autenticación básica en un rest api de *Codeigniter 4*, pero me responde lo siguiente:

> Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

class WebServiceCitasController extends ResourceController
{

     protected $modelName = 'App\Models\WebservicecitasModel';
     protected $format    = 'json';

     public function index()
     {
       
       $usuario_ws=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
       $password_ws=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
       if($usuario_ws=='admin'&& $password_ws=="123456789"){
       
            
            return $this->genericResponse($this->model->listarCitas(),"",200);
         }else{
          return $this->genericResponse("Error, no te haz autenticado","",200);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: puede usar token generados por sistema, pasarlos por `password_hash` y validarlos con `password_verify`; y te recomendaria usar el parametro de `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` ojo esto es php puro y tiene poco que ver con codeigniter. si quieres mas apoyo sobre el tema con mi idea me lo dejas saber para pasarte algo mas de código.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, claro que si me gustaria aprender algo nuevo, te agradezco me compartas tu conocimiento de antemano, mil gracias

Comment: mi idea no depende de la autenticación con $_SERVER depende usuarios registrados y almacenados en una base de datos... y en ves de hacer login en una web lo que harías es autenticarlos cuando consumen el api... incluso a los datos en la base de datos le puedes agregar un control de peticiones por X cantidad de segundos... XD

Comment: genial y como lo haria, sabes me gustaria aprender a crear un token y que caduque cada 60 min,sabes como se haria?

Comment: se hace del mismo modo que cuando registra un usuario en una web y despues hace un login solo que debes hacerlo para que funcione con tu rest; opcion 1: https://codeshack.io/secure-login-system-php-mysql/ opcion 2: https://www.webscodex.com/2020/08/php-login-registration-script-by-using.html

Comment: y asegúrate de usar: PASSWORD_BCRYPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione aplicando el poerador ternario para que me la asigne en vacia y asi ya me responde el ws.

```html
$usuario_ws=isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])?$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']:"";
   $password_ws=isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])?$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']:"";
```

Comment: pero eso no resuelve el problema, cualquier que no la tenga puede tener acceso entonces XD